# Writing a bitmap to Epson TM88IV through ESC/P commands (Write To NVRam)

Tags: c#, .net, printing, command, epson

Ref links:

1. https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ceLtiOLVtME/UMBL1yf4RpI/AAAAAAAAAD0/itid5KibW_I/s1015/Doc1.png
2. https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-nrphBDA6sjk/UMA_Ukh7ZSI/AAAAAAAAADY/LwjkgobOaBg/s846/MappingTable.png

**Updated**

I have changed the image convertion by using the LockBits now but failed. Does anyone can give me some suggestion?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Orginal command Format in Decimal:
    /// 29[GS], 40[(], 76[L], pL, PH, 48(m), 67[fn], 48[a], kc1, kc2, b, xL, xH, yL, yH, c, [d1 -- dk]
    /// pL = Lower bit of sum of parameters (m to dk) = 11(m to c) + last bit of image
    /// pH = Higher bit of sum of parameters (m to dk) = 11(m to c) + last bit of image
    /// kc = Key Code of NVRam, kc1 = first bit of key code, kc2 = second bit of key code. P.S.: The key code will be hardcode H1.
    /// b = number of colors = 1
    /// xL & xH = Lower bit of image width, e.g. Width = 128 = 0x0080 then xL = 0x80, xH = 0x00
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pLogo"></param>
    public void LoadImageToPrinter(Bitmap pLogo)
    {
        BitmapData oBmpData = pLogo.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pLogo.Width, pLogo.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, pLogo.PixelFormat);

        //The list contains all the commands in Decimal format
        List<int> oCommandList = new List<int>();

        //k = (int((xL + xH × 256) + 7)/8) × (yL + yH × 256)

        string HexValueOfX = pLogo.Width.ToString("X4");
        string HexValueOfY = pLogo.Height.ToString("X4");

        //k
        int oExpectedImageByteCount = Math.Abs(oBmpData.Stride) * pLogo.Height;

        //Total bit used for parameters
        int oTotalParameterBitCount = 11 + oExpectedImageByteCount;

        //The hex value for the oTotalParameterBitCount
        string oTotalParameterBitCountInHex = oTotalParameterBitCount.ToString("X4").PadLeft(4, '0');

        //GS, (, L
        oCommandList.AddRange(new int[] { 29, 40, 76 });

        //pL
        oCommandList.Add(GetLowerHexValue(oTotalParameterBitCountInHex));

        //pH
        oCommandList.Add(GetHigherHexValue(oTotalParameterBitCountInHex));

        //m,  fn, a,  kc1, kc2, b
        oCommandList.AddRange(new int[] { 48, 67, 48, (int)'H', (int)'1', 1 });

        //xL, xH
        oCommandList.AddRange(new int[] { GetLowerHexValue(HexValueOfX), GetHigherHexValue(HexValueOfX) });

        //yL, yH, c
        oCommandList.AddRange(new int[] { GetLowerHexValue(HexValueOfY), GetHigherHexValue(HexValueOfY), 49 });

        //Append the image bit to the List
        byte[] oImageByte = new byte[oExpectedImageByteCount];
        IntPtr oPtr = oBmpData.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(oPtr, oImageByte, 0, oExpectedImageByteCount);
        pLogo.UnlockBits(oBmpData);

        //Clear NVRam
        mThermalPrinterLibrary.Write(new int[] { 29, 40, 76, 5, 0, 48, 65, 67, 76, 82 }.IntArrayToCharString());

        //Store graphics data
        mThermalPrinterLibrary.Write(oCommandList.ToArray().IntArrayToCharString());
        mThermalPrinterLibrary.Write(oImageByte);

        //Print the graphics data
        mThermalPrinterLibrary.Write(new int[] { 29, 40, 76, 6, 0, 48, 69, (int)'H', (int)'1', 1, 1 }.IntArrayToCharString());        
}
```

Comment: You appear to be adding one byte per pixel: this is wrong; each byte represents 8 pixels.  Also you've named a variable 'oExpectedImageBitCount'.  'oExpectedImageByteCount' would be better.

Comment: Updated the variable name but I am still don't how to converting the bitmap into a byte array in the right way, sorry. No any image process experience before, what should I look for in google or somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: this is not specific to image processing, just bit manipulation. You seem to have code to get pixels (pLogo.GetPixel).  Each byte of the output represents 8 pixels: 0x80 is the first, 0x40 is the second, ... 0x01 the eighth.  You just need code to process pixels 8 at a time and set bits appropriately, e.g. using the bitwise shift operatior (<<).

Comment: Would you explain the table of the second ref link to me please? Thanks

Comment: both links seem to be broken :-(

Answer (score 5):

I've done this before many years ago, in C.  I don't have the code to hand, but it's more than just a snippet.  To do this you will need to do the following.

- Understand the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) - assuming you're reading your Bitmap from a file.
- Look at WINGDI.H (Microsoft Windows SDK) which has C-style definitions of the file headers etc: BITMAPFILEHEADER, BITMAPCOREHEADER, BITMAPINFOHEADER.
- Process the headers to determine if the bitmap meets your requirement (for example, to simplify your processing, you might want to insist that the bitmap is exactly 128 x 98 (BITMAPINFOHEADER.biWidth,  BITMAPINFOHEADER.biHeight), has one plane (BITMAPINFOHEADER.biPlanes = 1), is monochrome (BITMAPINFOHEADER.biBitCount =1 ), is not compressed (BITMAPINFOHEADER.biCompression = 0).  These restrictions aren't absolutely necessary, but will simplify your processing.
- Process the pixel array, and convert it to the format required for the ESCPOS escape sequence.

Alternatively, you might want to abandon using ESCPOS, and instead use OPOS / UPOS / POS for .NET, which provides a higher-level API for accessing POS peripherals: the POSPrinter device [exposes a method to print a bitmap](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/posfordotnet/thread/cb323bd3-052a-4626-9615-846bf17ca79c), and avoids you needing to do the format conversion yourself.  You'll need to download the [Epson OPOS ADK](http://www.pos.epson-europe.com/support/drivers.htm) to do this.
Good luck!

**UPDATE**

> And the document from EPSON just like hell, doesn't understand what it needs.

What's your difficulty with [the document from Epson](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/36/yLh-ESCPOS_AppProgGuideV10-05.pdf)?  Maybe you could try asking specific questions about the bits you don't understand.

**UPDATE 2**

Here are some pointers:

- **GS ( L pL pH m fn [params]** : pL and pH are the low- and high-order bytes of a 16-bit integer value that specifies the length in bytes of the following data (i.e. **m fn [params]**).
- For fn = 67 (Define NV data raster format), the format is **GS ( L pL pH m fn a kc1 kc2 b xL xH yL yH [c d1...dk]1...[c d1...dk]b** where m = 48, fn = 67, a = 48.
- kc1 and kc2 are key codes used to identify the downloaded data when you print it
- b specifies the number of colors for the downloaded data, 1 for monochrome, 2 for two-color.
- xL and xH are low- and high-order bytes of a 16-bit integer value that defines the width in dots (pixels) of the image.
- yL and yH are low- and high-order bytes of a 16-bit integer value that defines the height in dots (pixels) of the image.
- For a monochrome bitmap there will be one block **c d1 ... dk** that specifies the color **c** and the pixel data.  For color bitmaps, there is one block **c d1 ... dk** per color.
- The pixel data **d1 ... dk** has **k** bytes where k = (width x (height+7))/8.  A bit set to 1 means print that dot (pixel).

I don't know if the above is any clearer to you than the notes in the Epson documentation; if not say which bits you don't understand.

**UPDATE 3**

Here's an example based on a 128 width x 98 height bitmap as indicated in your question, monochrome for simplicity.

- You'll need k = (int(width + 7)/8) × (height) = (int(128+7)/8) x 98 = 16 x 98 = 1568 bytes of pixel data (bit = 1 means dot printed): d<sub>1</sub> to d<sub>1568</sub>
- Assume color c = Color 1 = 49 decimal = 0x31 hex (could also be 0x32 or 0x33)
- Width = 128 = 0x0080, so xH = 0x00, xL = 0x80
- Height = 98 = 0x0062, so yH = 0x00, yL = 0x62
- b = number of colors = 1
- Assume your key is "H1", i.e. kc1 = 'H' = 0x48 and kc2 = '1' = 0x31
- param length = length of **m fn a kc1 kc2 b xL xH yL yH c d<sub>1</sub> ... d<sub>1568</sub>** = 11 + 1568 = 1579 = 0x062B hex, so pL = 0x2B, pH = 0x06.

So the data you send will be:

**GS ( L pL pH m fn a kc1 kc2 b xL xH yL yH c d<sub>1</sub>...d<sub>1568</sub>**

In Hex:

1D 28 4C 2B 06 30 43 30 48 31 01 80 00 62 00 31 d<sub>1</sub> ... d<sub>1568</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried to use POS.Net(OPOS) but I found that the library was not stable as ESC/P.(Too long to tell)

And the document from EPSON just like hell, doesn't understand what it needs.
Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and patient but I only understand the point 2 & 3. May be I should found another way to store the bitmap like using some utilities from Epson :(

Anyway, thanks for you kindly reply

Comment: Much appreciate!! I will try to write some codes in C# and try to send to the printer. And will post it here, Thanks!!!

Comment: @Joe how to get the d1...d1568 format? do you loop through image Height and image width then get the pixel data? using this as basis for my c# code but it prints gibberish.